# A method for obtaining an object of type Class

Tags: java

In my textbook I can read:

If T is any Java type, then `T.class` is the matching class object. For example:

```
Class cl1 = Date.class; // if you import java.util.*; 
Class cl2 = int.class;
Class cl3 = Double[].class;
```

Later on I'm reading:

The virtual machine manages a unique Class object for each type. Therefore, you can use the `==` operator to compare class objects. For example:

```
if (e.getClass() == Employee.class)
```

Could you help me find anything about this .class field in the documentation. 
And another qutstion - I can't understand whether the **`e.getClass() == Employee.class`** is the same as `e.class == Employee.class`. I mean, if it is the same, why the author of the textbook used `getClass` here in the lefthand expression.

Comment: `e.class` (assuming `e` isn't a `class`) isn't a valid line of code.

Comment: Look in the javadoc: java.lang.Object and java.lang.Class.  X.class is called a "class literal".

Comment: @Josh M, I can't understand you, pardon. In my textbook I read: "Note that a Classobject really describes a type, which may or may not be a class. For 
example,intis not a class, but int.classis nevertheless an object of type Class.".

Comment: @Apprentice Queue, I have looked at both of them. Could you clarify where exactly in the docs for these classes should I look?

Comment: @Kifsif, are you sure you looked?  It's on the very last 2 sentences of java.lang.Class class summary in the Java 6 and Java 7 javadoc.

Comment: Sure. It seems to be a mistace in those 2 sentences as they are talking about class literals whereas their example is about getName(). Anyway, I looked at the specification mentioned in those sentences. Thank you. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS §15.8.2 - Class Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class.
>   The type of C.class, where C is the name of a class, interface, or array type (§4.3), is Class.

So, `Date.class`, `int.class` are nothing but class literals, which give appropriate `Class` objects for a class type.

> I can't understand whether the e.getClass() == Employee.class is the same as e.class == Employee.class

No, they are not the same. In fact, `e.class` won't even compile. As per the definition of class literal above, since `e` is not a type but an object of `Employee` (I assume that), `e.class` is not a valid class literal. To get the Class object of a class, using it's instance, you need to use [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method.

So, `e.getClass()` and `Employee.class` are two different ways to obtain the `Class` object for `Employee` class. Both to be used in different circumstances. When you know the class type, use 2<sup>nd</sup> version, and when you have an instance of your class, use the 1<sup>st</sup> version.

However, note that in case of inheritance, `e.getClass()` might not return the same Class object as `Employee.class`. The former would return the Class object of the actual subclass object, referred by the reference `e`, whereas the later would always give you `Class<Employee>`.

If you neither have the instance, nor the class type available, then you can also get the Class object for a class name in String form, using - [`Class#forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: 1+ to you and Ms. Shanahan's answers, both including links to the JLS.

Answer (score 2):

How you get a Class object depends on what you already know. If you have an object referenced by x, you can obtain the Class object for its class by x.getClass(). If you know, when you are writing your code, the name of a type T, you can use T.class to get the class object. There is a third approach, less convenient, that only requires run time access to the class name.

The getClass method is described as one of the Object methods, in the [Object API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29).

Class literals, the T.class form, are described in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.8.2).

The third approach uses one of the static forName methods defined the API documentation for [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).